# Connect Windows File Share with SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, folder, file, mapped-folder

Is it possible that we can connection File Share with SharePoint Foundation 2013?

So that we can view files and folders on SharePoint.

Comment: Having difficulty understanding what exactly you are asking here. But Erics answer does make sense. There is no OOTB where you can use SharePoint to browse non related network files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking whether you can leave files in a file share and access them through SharePoint with the out-of-the-box features then the answer is no.  There are however, 3rd party solutions out there that you can look at such as the "File Share Library" by Bamboo Solutions or I believe AvePoint also has a solution.

On the other hand, if you are asking if you can access files that live in SharePoint libraries via Windows Explorer then answer is yes. You can map a network drive via WebDAV using your SharePoint URL.

Comment: Can you please share the link that claims that it is not possible OOTB

Comment: There is no documentation because exposing network files shares as libraries is not a native feature of any version (v1 - 2013) of SharePoint thus far.